# Querying the active elements of a table per month when you only have access to Start and End Dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

to compile a report, I currently have to design a query that takes a table of Projects.
Each Project has a start and an enddate.
What's expected is for me to design a query, that selects the active Projects for each month.

What I am doing right now is executing 2 Select statements:
The first counts Project that were finished and groups them by month, so I have all Projects that were finished within a month.

THe second one counts all Projects that started but did not finish until at least 1 month later.

Then I join them on Month and Year, and add up the 2 counts.

THe Problem I noticed, is that this disregards Projects that neither ended, nor were created within that month, meaning Projects that stretched over it.
Example: A Project created in January, and finished in March will not be counted in February.

Is there a way to do this without creating another select for each potential length of a Project?
Like:
One select that counts all projects that were created last month but not finished this month, then the same for those created 2 months in the past, and so on.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Join to a calendar table with months in it using `tab.end_date >= cal.start_date and tab.start_date <= cal.end_date` (depending on your implementation `<=` might be `<`)

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Suggested reading: [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually built a Calendar Table by selecting month and year from all possible Startdates of Projects and then use a join to attach each project to every month it was active in.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SQL dialect, something like this should do the trick ?

```
select * from projects p 
where sysdate between p.startDate 
              and coalesce(p.endDate, to_date('2040-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just count all projects that are currently active?
It selects everything from projects p where my systemtime is between the startdate and the enddate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, something like this could help.

```
Select ProjectsStarted = Sum(Case When ProjectStartDate between MonthStart and MonthEnd Then 1 Else 0 End)
,      ProjectsEnded = Sum(Case When ProjectEndDate between MonthStart and MonthEnd Then 1 Else 0 End)
,      ContinuingProjects = Sum(Case When ProjectStartDate < MonthStart AND (ProjectEndDate > MonthEnd OR ProjectEndDate is null) Then 1 Else 0)
From   tblProjects
```